# Building large S-Boxes from smaller ones

Tags: algorithm-design, s-boxes

I would like to make an exhaustive list of all relevant techniques that have been studied in order to build a large S-Box from smaller ones.
As far as I known, three structures are usually preferred:

1. The Lai-Massey construction (used to design the IDEA block cipher)
2. Feistel networks (used to build $2n$-bit permutations from $n$-bit permutations)
3. MISTY networks (initially combines an $(n-1)$-bit S-Box with an $(n+1)$-bit one [in this document](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ee79/19e42245d85c9a85b2c34a2adbfe232d65c1.pdf))

Notably, [this publication](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/711.pdf) analyzes pros and cons of using either Feistel or MISTY networks to build 8-bit S-Boxes.

Are there any other relevant techniques to design large S-Boxes from smaller ones?

Comment: also see unbalanced s-boxes like the 8x32-bit s-boxes in blowfish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , there are others such as SPN (CLEFIA , Khazad Middori-128 ,etc)

in addition to xor-based Feistel  structure , the Kuznyechik is based on product-based Feistel  structure.

I suggest to read this thesis (it summaries all) : [CRYPTANALYSIS, REVERSE-ENGINEERING AND DESIGN OF SYMMETRIC CRYPTOGRAPHIC ALGORITHMS](http://orbilu.uni.lu/bitstream/10993/31195/1/thesis.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I think all the block cipher structures like spn or feistel can make small s-box into a big one since you can view the block cipher as a big s-box.

Comment: I think the only time someone asked about a 64-bit s-box I told them to use DES with a fixed key

Comment: I agree with you. Small s-boxes with some good permutation layers will make a good big one.